# Connecting user from AMP to nonAMP pages

Tags: analytics, amp-html, amp-analytics

Looking at google's AMP documentation, seems like clientID is a great way to store a unique user id. But how can I translate that through my regular non amp page? If a user sees an AMP page and got a clientID, then they performed some operation which led them to land on non AMP page. As I don't have access to old cookies on google's cache domain, how can I relate AMP clientID with my new generated clientID on NON AMP page?

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/client-id), non-AMP pages uses a single, first-party cookie named `_ga` to store the client ID (on the publisher domain). In this case the user goes directly to publisher's domain to view a non-AMP page. The client ID is stored in cookie(`_ga`) and is used/reused as needed. You can check this related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1619).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a proxy as shown in https://github.com/andreban/amp-publisher-sample/commit/c455a2d117a8899dcb201f93e17889f4d2681cd3 should work for this case. Note that the example is for google analytics but you can easily use the technique for other providers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up doing the same thing.